# Automatização de tarefas no linux

Tags: python, linux, shell-script

Bom, eu já conheço python e sei que ela é muito boa pra trabalhar com scripts e automatização de tarefas mas minha duvida é, eu consigo trabalhar confortavelmente com administração e automatização de ambientes linux e banco de dados apenas com o python ou é mais interessante eu aprender shell script para fazer esse trabalho?

Comment: trabalhar em q?

Comment: Algumas tarefas você poderá fazer diretamente em Python, porém outras ficam mais simples diretamente em shell. Uma dica é você unir as duas coisas e experimentar o Ansible.

Answer (score 2):

Se você partir para  a automatização de bancos de dados vai perceber que o bash logo o limitará, o python possui bibliotecas fantásticas como o sqlalchemy e conectores nativos para praticamente todos os bancos de dados, tanto relacionais quanto não relacionais.

Além de você poder automatizar tarefas com o python em qualquer plataforma, então seu conhecimento no linux não se perderá por exemplo se for para o windows.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que seja mais confortável utilizar uma linguagem que já é de costume.

[image: PYTHON NO LINUX]

Veja o item "Aplicações" no [Wikipédia - Python](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python).

Uma pergunta parecida foi feita no SO em inglês ([StackOverflow Question -> Shell Script: Execute a python program from within a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377109/shell-script-execute-a-python-program-from-within-a-shell-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).